# Remove text before the first number in a test string with Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to remove all text before the first number with jQuery. Here's an example:

> ```
> Hand knotted in Iran (Persian)<br>Wool on wool<br>3.6m x 2.8m<br>11' 10" x 9' 2"
> ```

The output i would like is:

> ```
> 3.6m x 2.8m<br>11' 10" x 9' 2"
> ```

I have tried the following:

```
$('.ProductItem__Desc').each(function(){
  $(this).text(function(_, text) {
    return (text.split([0-9]).pop());
  });
});
```

Not a massive expert with regex and jQuery. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Match using `^\D*` and replace with an empty string. https://regex101.com/r/PDAKho/1 or match `\d.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot of solution:

```
var str = Hand knotted in Iran (Persian)<br>Wool on wool<br>3.6m x 2.8m<br>11' 10" x 9' 2";

var newstr = str.replace(/^\D*/g, "");
```

or

```
var newstr = str.replace(/^[^0-9]*/g, "");
```